# Chartjs: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'HALF_PI')

Tags: chart.js

I've migrated from Chartjs 2.x to 3.5 and I'm having the error below:

```
chartjs.helpers.v3.5.1.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'HALF_PI')
    at chartjs.helpers.v3.5.1.js:5
```

My versions:
"chart.js": "^3.5.1",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@types/chart.js": "^2.9.34",

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js v3 comes with build in typing, the `@types/chart.js` are only for v2 so you will need to uninstall it

```sh
npm uninstall @types/chart.js

yarn remove @types/chart.js
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.
I uninstalled the package but the bug persists.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this error by migrating properly from v2 to v3, using this guide https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html.

I can't seem to find exactly where the bug is, but it seems to be related to chartjs-plugin-datalabels